Hello, I am having trouble understanding why the graph of the function shifts to the right and not the left.
As you can see in this graph, there are equivalent points on functions g and f. The relation between $g$ and $f$ is $g(x) = f(x-2)$. As the $x$ value is decreased, why doesn't the graph move to the left instead of the right? This is generally the case of horizontally shifting functions, but I can't understand why. (This image is a screenshot from the "Identifying Function Transformations" video on Khan Academy.)
g(-1) = f(-3)
g(0) = f(-2)
g(1) = f(-1)

I like to think of it as ‘where does x act like 0’. At two. So the graph is two to the right.

$f(x-2)$ have same value as $f(x)$ on $2$ units to the right to balance the subtraction in the argument.

It depends on which graph you speak, of the function g or f ?

Does this answer your question? (It discusses both shifting and stretching.) Mechanics of Horizontal Stretching and Shrinking

Writing, say, $f(x-2)$ fools the function $f$ into thinking that $x=12$, $x=34$, and $x=12345$ are only $10$, $32$, and $12343$, so the plot effectively shifts $2$ units to the right.

When we move the graph two units right we are applying the transformation $x_{new}=x_{old}+2$
In terms of $x_{old}$ this is $x_{old}=x_{new}-2$
So $f(x_{old})$ moved two units to the right becomes $f(x_{new}-2)$ and we say the image of $f(x)$ is $f(x-2)$.
Hope this makes sense.
